# Contradicting code causing multiple images

Tags: iphone, ios, image, image-resizing

I have some code that allows me to enlarge and then shrink to normal size a picture but if I tap on the picture too many times it creates a large version of that picture or the picture that was in the view before it and it is unable to be resized. I am not sure but I think there might be a contradiction or something between the addSubview statements of both of these pieces of code. This is the implementation for `ImageEnlarge`.

```
@implementation ImageEnlarge


-(UIImageView *)internal{
return internal;
}

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
      if (self) {
    internal = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    [internal setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [internal setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    [self addSubview:(internal)];
    }
   return self;
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)touch {

   if (isLarge) [self makeSmall];
   else [self makeFull];
}

-(void) makeFull {

  [[self superview] bringSubviewToFront:self];
  isLarge = YES;    
  CGSize largePicSize = CGSizeMake(156, 156);
  CGPoint largePicOrigin = CGPointMake(110, 96);
  CGRect largeFrame;
  largeFrame.size = largePicSize;
  largeFrame.origin = largePicOrigin;
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
  [internal setFrame:self.bounds];
  [self setFrame:largeFrame];
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void) makeSmall {

  isLarge = NO;    
  CGSize normPicSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
  CGPoint normPicOrigin = CGPointMake(82, 74);
  CGRect original;
  original.size = normPicSize;
  original.origin = normPicOrigin;
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
  [internal setFrame:self.bounds];
  [self setFrame:original];
  [UIView commitAnimations];

}

@end
```

Here is the implementation of this on my image.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData *albumArtImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.churchwebserver.org/imagename.jpg"]];


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIImage *albumArt = [UIImage imageWithData:albumArtImageData];
        CGSize picSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
        CGPoint picOrigin = CGPointMake(110, 96);
        CGRect picFrame;
        picFrame.size = picSize;
        picFrame.origin = picOrigin;
        ImageEnlarge * imEn =[[ImageEnlarge alloc]initWithFrame:picFrame];
        [[imEn internal]setImage:albumArt];
        [self.view addSubview:(imEn)];
```

The question also remains why it takes two touches for the image to respond initially and after that it works every touch and why I can touch in a close proximity to the image and it still sense that I am touching the actual image? So many questions.

Answer (score -1):

It is getting touches around the image because probably the image has a black border. Did you check that ?

Comment: It has a black background not a black border.

Comment: I was talking about the image inside the UIImageview